# Do all $n \times n$ diagonal matrices form a group under matrix multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that diagonal matrices are square matrices whose only non-zero entries lie on the main diagonal but I'm not sure how to incorporate that into my response.

Comment: It's not true. As a counterexample, try to find an $n \times n$ diagonal matrix that doesn't have a multiplicative inverse. Your knowledge that diagonal matrices with only non-zero diagonal entries should tell you where to start looking.

Comment: I highly recommend that you study [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Answer (score 7):

You must remove all the matrices that have zero entries on the main diagonal because these matrices do not have an inverse. If you take only the diagonal matrices with no zeros on the diagonal then it is a group. (it is a subgroup of the general linear group)